# What's the best flow for authentication using Firebase in NextJS and ExpressJS system

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, next.js

I'm currently developing a front-end system (build using NextJS) and backend (build using Node/ExpressJS). I'm using Firebase for the authentication system. Users can log in / signup to the website using email/password, Google or Facebook login. The system also needs to store user data on its own, and it uses the Postgres database for its persistence storage.

Currently, this is what I have:

For Registration

- with username and password

  - user fill in the sign-up form
  - frontend call the `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`
  - frontend call the `/register` endpoint on the backend with the Authorization header consists of the token that's generated from the above step
- with google / login

  - user click on the sign up with Google / Facebook button
  - frontend call the firebase method to open up a popup for Google / Facebook login
  - frontend call the `/register` endpoint on the backend with the Authorization header consists of the token that's generated from the previous step.

For Login

- with username/password

  - frontend call the `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` and store the token generated from the response in cookie
  - all of the subsequent requests to the backend will use the token as an Authorization header

The only thing that I'm still not quite sure about is Google / Facebook because it uses the same firebase function. How to differentiate between login/registration for the social media login apart? And is there a better way for the system to ensure that the user data is created in the database? At the moment, when the `/register` endpoint throws an error, I'll call the `firebase.auth().deleteUser` function afterwards.

I believe this must be a common scenario for a website that uses Firebase authentication. I really appreciate any suggestions.